# Double edge swap 3x3

Tags: rubiks-cube

So I looked into this a little bit, what's odd is my cube can be scrambled and solved unlike cubes that were assembled or reassembled incorrectly, so they always get this situation. My cube is a standard moyu speed cube, the corners and edges cannot be flipped without breaking them off, I have not had to reassemble it yet. The cube has been manufactured correctly. [image] I only got this situation because I used basic algorithms. What's an algorithm for when 2 opposite top edges need to be swapped to solve?

Comment: I don't think this is possible??? I think you did something weird.

Comment: I've seen people say that you can get this with basic algorithms.

Comment: Both those people have somethong wrong with their cube where they can't solve it. I can scramble and solve it. EDIT: Though I did use that picture because it describes my situation. Yet all of the algorithms on that post just reset the lat layer. I want to know how to solve it from this state.

Comment: It cannot be solved with normal moves only. If you cannot disassemble the edges/corners, what you could do to make it solvable is to rearrange the caps of the centres.

Comment: I can solve it using normal moves, I've been solving it for the last 40 minutes now. I just needed reset the last layer with something like R U R' U R U2 R'. I just want to know how to solve it from this state, not by reseting layers.

Comment: You have something wrong with your cube, just like those other two duplicate posts. It is mathematically impossible to swap two pieces in isolation using normal moves only, because every move is equivalent to an even number of swaps and can never be the same as an odd number of swaps. The only way to return your cube to a normal solved state is to disassemble it (possibly just the centre caps).

Comment: It's currently in a solved state. Normally I care about theoretical mathematics, but this was a situation I got yesterday. EDIT: One weird thing with it is that I got this when I put the last edge in place.

Comment: Then you are mistaken. There must have been other pieces that were unsolved in addition to the two edge pieces. (EDIT: or you mistook two flipped edge pieces for an edge swap)

Comment: It's possible, I can't really remember things, and I can't be 100% sure. Thanks

Comment: Happened me once. Had ti give it to my girl to scrumble enough to get back to normale state. However I would Like ti obtain an algorithm for that.